# how do i resolve An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details

Tags: java, android-studio, appium-android

I am trying to create a new Android virtual device in Android Studio and seeing the error as **"An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details."**

when I open the idea.log it is as it is in the image.
in addition to the one which is there in the image there are also other exceptions as listed below

```
    1) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    2) java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    3)java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native
    C:\Users\w159chpu\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2022.1\tmp\jna8592839284912440723.dll: Access is denied
```

Can someone please help me resolve this?